# Database and Azure Queue Trigger: How to prevent Concurrently access database resources

Tags: azure, concurrency, duplicates, queuetrigger

I am looking in this blog

https://medium.com/@yuka1984/azure-functions-%E3%81%AE-singletonattribute%E3%81%A8mode%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%91%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3-bb728062198e

This singleton with batch size 1 will enable the queue be executed the queue function once at a time on one instance even the function scale out. Why I need this is, I wanted to prevent the database called by the azure function not to update the same table concurrently making inconsistent with the data.

E.g. Instance A execute an check data in database and modified some values. At the same time, Instance B execute an check data in database and modified the values also. Expected result is A modified data first than instance B but B execute faster than Instance A, so Instance B updated first. Which was not my expected result.

Order of execution is fine but i don't want to be mixed up of insert of data.

Instance A has Data [1,2,3,4]
Instance B has Data [2,4,6,7]

If execute either A or B, the outcome would be [1,2,3,4,6,7]
If execute concurrently, there is a chance having [1,2,2,3,4,6,7]

At the time of executing A may not have '2' in the table yet while executing B. Therefore B inserted '2' as well. In this case, I have duplication of data.

Does the blog guaranteed to fulfill the requirement? Is there other options?

Comment: When I run my queue trigger with Singleton Mode : Function in my local machine. The result i have was sequentially executed. Once I removed the Singleton, my queue trigger picked up and execute concurrently. The way i test this is just a line of console printout follow a five second delays. I am not sure will this work in multiple instances the same way as this.